# how to change the background color of a html section depending on the result of an array

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an array which picks a movie at random and below I have movie posters , I just click on the poster and it brings me to the movie on netflix, it would be great if the surrounding color of the movie poster changed to green so that it would be easier to find.

javascript

```
function GetValue()
{
    var myarray= new Array("13 assassins"); // just an example
    var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];

    document.randform.randomfield.value = random;
}

        </script>
```

html

```
<body>
       <Div id=maincontent>
            <section id="topcontent">
       <form name="randform">
        <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Click for a random movie"    onclick="GetValue();" />
        <input type="text" name="randomfield" value="" size="50">
        </form>

            <section id="movies">

               <!--13 assassins -->
             <div id="movie">


                <a  href="link to film">
                    <img src="images/13.jpg" alt="player" width="225" height="325">
                </a>

            </div>
```

css

```
#movie{
   margin-top:5%;
    width:225px;
    height:325px;
    float:left;
    background-color:whitesmoke; //want this to be green when the movie is picked
    border-radius:5px; 
    margin-left:2%;
    padding:2% 3%;
    margin-bottom:2%;
    margin-right:2%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function GetValue()
{
    var myarray= new Array("13 assassins"); // just an example
    var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];

    document.randform.randomfield.value = random;
    document.getElementById(random).style.border = "2px solid green";// use this if you have multiple images .and to identify each image give the same id as the values in your array
   
   // but if you want to set border to div movie then do this:
 document.getElementById('movie').style.border = "2px solid green";// comment it if not required

}
```

```css
#movie{
   margin-top:5%;
    width:225px;
    height:325px;
    float:left;
    background-color:whitesmoke; //want this to be green when the movie is picked
    border-radius:5px; 
    margin-left:2%;
    padding:2% 3%;
    margin-bottom:2%;
    margin-right:2%; 
}
```

```html
<div id=maincontent>
            <section id="topcontent">
       <form name="randform">
        <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Click for a random movie"    onclick="GetValue();" />
        <input type="text" name="randomfield" value="" size="50">
        </form>

            <section id="movies">

               <!--13 assassins -->
             <div id="movie" >


                <a  href="link to film">
                    <img src="images/13.jpg" alt="player" width="225" height="325" id="13 assassins">
                </a>

            </div>
            </section>
```

Comment: for some reason this messes with my stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

You can change css with jquery

```
$("#movie").css("background-color", "green");
```

If you have a set and get div for film, you can set div id for every film. You can use database id for film.

```
$("#film356").css("background-color", "green");
```